# Why Is SwiftUI View Populated With Injected Object Only After Second Presentation of the View

Tags: swiftui

I have a project which uses Core Data to store measurement values. The user can add new measurements to be persisted, and the user can edit persisted measurements.

The issue that I am experiencing is seen when attempting to edit a persisted measurement. After selecting a persisted measurement, the user is presented with the view to edit and save the measurement. The selected measurement is passed from the list to the presented view, where the value populates a `TextField`. Unfortunately, the value does not populate the `TextField` when the view is presented the first time within the app. Only after the second presentation does the measurement value populate the `TextField`.

The user can present the view to add a new measurement to be persisted, cancel and dismiss it, select an existing measurement, and that measurement's value will be displayed in the presented `TextField`. It seems that the initial presentation of the view used to add/edit a measurement does not contain the selected measurement on the first presentation. Only after the first presentation and dismissal will the value populate the `TextField`.

Below, you can see a 22sec GIF, which displays the current behavior.

[image: GIF of Xcode Simulator replicating described issue]

In the GIF, you can see that a persisted measurement is selected, and the presented view's `TextField` is not populated with the measurement's value. Only on the second presentation is it populated. The last half of the GIF shows the process for persisting a new measurement and that the `TextField` is populated with that measurement's value on a subsequent presentation.

If you wish to reproduce the described behavior, then you can find the project's repository [here](https://github.com/nickkohrn/ParameterLog/tree/feature/edit-measurement), using the `feature/edit-measurement` branch, which the URL points to.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Launch application
2. Select any parameter from the list
3. Tap the trailing navigation button
4. Enter a value into the `TextField`
5. Tap the Save button
6. Return to the root view (list of parameters)
7. Select the parameter of which you saved the measurement value in step 5
8. Select the newly-persisted measurement in the list
9. Notice the unpopulated `TextField`
10. Tap the cancel button or dismiss the view by dragging downward
11. Select the same measurement that was selected in step 7
12. Notice the populated `TextField`

Below is the implementation of the view that displays persisted measurements:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParameterMeasurementsLogView: View {

    // MARK: Properties

    let parameter: Parameter

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @StateObject private var measurementStore = MeasurementStore()

    @State private var displayMeasurementEntryView = false

    @State private var selectedMeasurementIndex: Int?

    private var measurementsRequest: FetchRequest<ParameterMeasurement>

    private var measurements: FetchedResults<ParameterMeasurement> { measurementsRequest.wrappedValue }

    private var measurementValues: [Double] { (measurements.map { $0.value }) }

    private var measurementDeltas: [Double?] { measurementValues.deltasBetweenElements() }

    private var measurementFormatter: MeasurementFormatter {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        formatter.numberFormatter = numberFormatter
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        formatter.unitStyle = .medium
        return formatter
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(measurements.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    selectedMeasurementIndex = index
                    displayMeasurementEntryView = true
                }, label: {
                    HStack(content: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(formattedMeasurement(at: index))
                            if index < measurements.count - 1 {
                                HStack(content: {
                                    Image(systemName: deltaIconName(at: index))
                                    Text(deltaString(for: index))
                                })
                            }
                            if let date = measurements[index].date {
                                FormattedDateTimeView(date: date)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteMeasurements(at:))
        }
        .navigationTitle(parameter.name)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            displayMeasurementEntryView = true
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: Icon.plusCircleFill)
        }))
        .sheet(isPresented: $displayMeasurementEntryView, onDismiss: {
            selectedMeasurementIndex = nil
        }) {
            ParameterMeasurementEntryView(parameter: parameter, entryMode: entryMode())
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)
        }
    }

    // MARK: Initialization

    init(parameter: Parameter) {
        self.parameter = parameter
        let entity = ParameterMeasurement.entity()
        let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(ParameterMeasurement.date), ascending: false)]
        let predicateFormat = "%K =[c] %@"
        let predicateArguments = [#keyPath(ParameterMeasurement.parameterName), parameter.name]
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateFormat, argumentArray: predicateArguments)
        measurementsRequest = FetchRequest(entity: entity, sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, animation: .none)
    }

    // MARK: Deletion

    private func deleteMeasurements(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { managedObjectContext.delete(measurements[$0]) }
        PersistenceStack.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: Helpers

    private func formattedMeasurement(at index: Int) -> String {
        let value = measurements[index].value
        switch parameter.measurementUnit {
        case .unitDispersion(units: _, defaultUnit: let unit):
            let measurement = Measurement<Unit>(value: value, unit: unit)
            return measurementFormatter.string(from: measurement)
        }
    }

    private func deltaIconName(at index: Int) -> String {
        guard let delta = measurementDeltas[index] else { fatalError("Expected delta") }
        if delta == 0 { return Icon.arrowUpArrowDown }
        return delta > 0 ? Icon.arrowUp : Icon.arrowDown
    }

    private func deltaString(for index: Int) -> String {
        guard let delta = measurementDeltas[index] else { return "" }
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        let absolute = abs(delta)
        guard let formatted = formatter.string(from: absolute as NSNumber) else { fatalError("Expected formatted delta") }
        return formatted
    }

    private func deltaBetweenMeasurement(at firstIndex: Int, and secondIndex: Int) -> Double {
        measurementValues[firstIndex] - measurementValues[secondIndex]
    }

    private func entryMode() -> MeasurementEntryMode {
        if let index = selectedMeasurementIndex {
            return .edit(measurement: measurements[index])
        }
        return .add
    }

}
```

Below, you can see the implementation of the view used to add/edit a measurement and persist it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParameterMeasurementEntryView: View {

    // MARK: Properties

    let parameter: Parameter

    let entryMode: MeasurementEntryMode

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
 
    @State private var measurementValueString = ""

    private var measurementValue: Double? { Double(measurementValueString) }

    private var cancelButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Text("Cancel")
        })
    }

    private var saveButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            saveNewMeasurement()
            dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Text("Save")
        })
        .disabled(disableSaveButton())
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(content: {
            Form(content: {
                Section(header: Text("Measurement")) {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Value", text: $measurementValueString)
                        Text(defaultUnitSymbol())
                    }
                }
            })
            .navigationTitle(parameter.name)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: cancelButton, trailing: saveButton)
            .onAppear(perform: setMeasurmentTextIfEditingMeasurement)
        })
    }

    // MARK: Initialization

    init(parameter: Parameter, entryMode: MeasurementEntryMode) {
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.entryMode = entryMode
    }

    // MARK: Helpers

    private func dismiss() {
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

    private func disableSaveButton() -> Bool {
        let measurementIsInvalid = measurementValue == nil
        if case let .edit(measurement) = entryMode {
            let enteredValueEqualsCurrentValue = Double(measurementValueString) == measurement.value
            return measurementIsInvalid || enteredValueEqualsCurrentValue
        }
        return measurementIsInvalid
    }

    private func saveNewMeasurement() {
        guard let value = measurementValue else { return assertionFailure("Expected measurement value") }
        let measurement = ParameterMeasurement(entity: ParameterMeasurement.entity(), insertInto: managedObjectContext)
        measurement.value = value
        measurement.date = Date()
        measurement.parameterName = parameter.name
        PersistenceStack.saveContext()
    }

    private func defaultUnitSymbol() -> String {
        switch parameter.measurementUnit {
        case .unitDispersion(_, defaultUnit: let defaultUnit): return defaultUnit.symbol
        }
    }

    private func setMeasurmentTextIfEditingMeasurement() {
        if case let .edit(measurment) = entryMode { measurementValueString = String(measurment.value) }
    }

}
```

`MeasurementEntryMode` is a simple `enum` that allows the list to tell the add/entry view if it's adding a new measurement or editing an existing one.

```
import Foundation

enum MeasurementEntryMode {

    // MARK: Cases

    case add, edit(measurement: ParameterMeasurement)

}
```

What is causing the persisted measurement's value to not be displayed in the `TextField` on the first presentation of the add/edit view but be displayed on the second presentation?

Even the following trivial example yields the same results:

```
struct PrimaryView: View {

    @State private var selectedIndex: Int?

    @State private var showDetail = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(0...50).indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Button(action: {
                        selectedIndex = index
                        showDetail = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text("\(index)")
                    })
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showDetail, onDismiss: {
                selectedIndex = nil
            }) {
                Text(String(describing: selectedIndex))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Justin Stanley's [response to my question](https://twitter.com/onlytruejustin/status/1280680800036544512) on Twitter, simply moving the code to set whether the detail view is shown from the `Button`'s action to an `View.onChange(of:perform:)` modifier fixes the issue.

[image: Screenshot of Twitter response from Justin Stanley displaying image of code]